# Is there an override that allows the __init__ of a class to create another class object instead?

Tags: python, sympy

This is pertaining to the sympy module. For example,

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = Mul(x * y)
type(expr) == Mul
```

will return true. However,

```
x, y = 1, 2
expr = Mul(x * y)
type(expr) == Mul
```

will return false. More specifically, expr in the second case is Integer(2) so I was wondering if Mul is a type, how does expr get created as an Integer? It's reasonable obviously since 1 * 2 should just be 2, not an expression but how do you go about achieving this? I've considered the possibility that Mul might be a function that returns depending on the case, but that doesn't explain how it can be a type as well

Comment: `.__init__()` is too late for this - the new instance has already been created.  But if you implement `.__new__()`, it's allowed to create an instance of a different class.

Comment: I see `Expr` and `Basic` in the `__mro__` for both objects.  `Basic` has a `__new__`.  I don't see `__init__` in any of these.  The class structure in `sympy` is much more advanced than the typical Python user knows.

Comment: Can you give a short example of this? I'm reading on it and it kind of makes sense but I still don't think I can reconstruct the implementation for this example. Not necessarily this specific one, but just one with the class changing

Answer (score 1):

This is done using `__new__` rather than `__init__`:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> class B:
...     def __new__(cls, arg):
...         if arg < 0:
...             return A()
...         else:
...             return super().__new__(cls)
... 
>>> B(1)
<__main__.B object at 0x7fc72df68b20>
>>> B(-1)
<__main__.A object at 0x7fc72df68880>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Comment: How does this work for when arguments are passed in? For example, B(x) creates B(x) if x is even and A(x) if x is odd?

Comment: You check the arguments in `__new__` and then return whatever you want.

Comment: I've extended the example slightly